# What are properties of $\operatorname E\{X1_A\}$?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have a question in my text about some function $Q : \mathcal A \to \mathbb R$, $Q$(*A*)= $E\{X1_A\}$, ($X \geq 0$ a.s. and $E\{X\} = 1$).

A later question built on this premise sets $E_Q$ as expectation with respect to $Q$. (Asking to show $E_Q\{Y\}=E_P\{YX\}$.)
Would that mean $E_Q(Y)=E\{E\{X1_Y\}\}$? Or $E_Q(Y)=E\{Y[E\{X1_Y\}]\}$? By the hint from the question, I'm inclined to the latter, but I'm a bit confused.

Also, if I understand correctly, $Q(A)= \sum\{x1_AP(x)\} = \sum_{x\in A} xP(x)$. I haven't reached conditional expectation yet, but this seems like $Q$ could be an expression for that. Am I way off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, in that conditional expectation indeed deals with expectations of the form $E(XI_A)$. I understand the temptation to try to use conditional expectation. However, in this case, interestingly, one can perfectly answer the question without needing conditional probability.

For simplicity, let's assume a finite possibility space $\Omega$ with probability mass function $p$. Then
$$Q(\{\omega\})=E(X I_{\omega})=X(\omega)p(\omega).$$ So,
$$E_Q(Y)=\sum_{\omega\in\Omega} Q(\{\omega\})Y(\omega)=\sum_{\omega\in\Omega} p(\omega)X(\omega)Y(\omega)=E(XY),$$
establishing the desired equality. All I've used here in the entire argument is the definition of expectation with respect to a probability mass function.

Something not asked but perhaps worth clarifying is that $Q$ actually defines a probability measure on the power set of $\Omega$. To see this, note that

1. $Q(\{\omega\})=p(\omega)X(\omega)\ge 0$ since $X\ge 0$ a.s. by assumption (which means that $X(\omega)\ge 0$ whenever $p(\omega)\neq 0$, provided $\Omega$ is finite).
2. For any $A\subseteq\Omega$ we have that $$Q(A)=E(XI_A)=\sum_{\omega\in A}p(\omega)X(\omega)=\sum_{\omega\in A}Q(\{\omega\})$$ so $Q$ will satisfy the additivity axiom.
3. Finally, $$Q(\Omega)=E(XI_{\Omega})=E(X)=1$$ by assumption.

In other words, $Q$ is a non-negative, additive, and normalized set function on the power set of $\Omega$, which means that it is a [probability measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_measure).

For the case where $\Omega$ is not finite, some additional details need to be considered, and I'll happily refer you to @Snoop's excellent answer for full technical details.

Comment: OK, so $E_Q$ just replaces $P(\omega)$ with $Q(\omega)$. That's the biggest part I was hung up on. It wasn't totally clear to me what "Expectation with respect to $Q$" meant. I had a clue as to that first chain of equalities you laid out, but it helps to be confirmed. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's right. @Snoop's answer is a bit more detailed and also proves that $Q$ actually defines a probability measure, and also takes care of the limit arguments that are needed when you're dealing with infinite spaces, but the argument remains essentially the same. I'll add some detail to show that $Q$ is a probability measure also here, since this isn't entirely obvious (even though that wasn't part of your question).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and the positive random variable $X:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}^+$. Basically, $Q:\mathcal{A}\to [0,1]$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$. To prove this, notice that
$$Q(\emptyset)=\int\mathbb{I}_\emptyset(\omega)X(\omega)\mu(d\omega)=0$$
$$Q(\Omega)=\int\mathbb{I}_\Omega(\omega)X(\omega)\mu(d\omega)=E[X]=1$$
and for disjoint $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\subset \mathcal{A}$ we have
$$Q(\cup_nA_n)=\int\mathbb{I}_{\cup_nA_n}(\omega)X(\omega)\mu(d\omega)=\int\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{I}_{A_n}(\omega)X(\omega)\mu(d\omega)= \\ =\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\int\mathbb{I}_{A_n}(\omega)X(\omega)\mu(d\omega)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}Q(A_n)$$
where I used monotone convergence to exchange the integral and the summation. In this way we can take expectations using the measure $Q$ for $Y$ which is integrable
$$E_Q[Y]:=\int Y(\omega)Q(d\omega)=\int \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum^{N(n)}_{k=0}\phi_{k,n}\mathbb{I}_{B_{n,k}}(\omega)Q(d\omega)= \\
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum^{N(n)}_{k=0}\phi_{k,n}Q(B_{n,k})= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum^{N(n)}_{k=0}\phi_{k,n}\int \mathbb{I}_{B_{n,k}}(\omega)X(\omega)\mu(d\omega)= \\ = \int \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum^{N(n)}_{k=0}\phi_{k,n}\mathbb{I}_{B_{n,k}}(\omega)X(\omega)\mu(d\omega)=\int Y(\omega)X(\omega)\mu(d\omega)= E[YX]$$
where I used a sequence of simple functions approximating $Y$ and dominated convergence to take the limits in and out the integral.

Comment: Great answer! I absolutely love the fact that you took care of the proper convergence.

Comment: Thank you!! @MatthiasC.M.Troffaes

Comment: I'm not completely clear on your notation for the simple functions. (I must confess, that is a part I get hung up on sometimes in my current text) Can you explain your indexing for $\phi$ and the indicator?

Comment: @OldDogNewTrick Every measurable function $Y$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$ is the pointwise limit of a sequence of simple functions $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $|Y_n|\leq |Y|$. Every simple function $Y_n$ in the sequence has its own number of indicators ($N+1$), coefficients ($\phi_k$) and indicator functions ($\mathbb{I}_{B_k}$). So they are also indexed by $n$.